# clojure retry library perseverance usage

Tags: clojure

Trying to use https://github.com/grammarly/perseverance,
why does the following fails? Ie. the last call still produces an exception

```
(defn fail-n
  "returns a function that will fail to process for the first n times is is called"
  [n]
  (let [cnt (atom 0)]
    (fn []
      (if (< @cnt n)
        (do (swap! cnt inc)
            (throw (RuntimeException. "Failed")))
        :success))))

(defn safe-fail-n [n]
  (p/retriable {
                ;;:catch [RuntimeException]
                } (fail-n n)))

;;(def f (fail-n 1))
(def f (safe-fail-n 2))

(p/retry {;;:strategy (p/constant-retry-strategy 0)
          ;;:catch [Exception]
          ;;:log-fn (fn [& a] (println "Retrying "a))
          }
          (f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the [github](https://github.com/grammarly/perseverance) readme, you have to catch the RE in the `p/retriable` form

otherwise nothing is catched - or retried

```
user=> (let [x (fail-n 5)] 
         (p/retry {} 
           (p/retriable {:catch [RuntimeException]} (x))))

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed, retrying in 0,5 seconds...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed, retrying in 0,5 seconds...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed, retrying in 0,5 seconds...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed, retrying in 1,0 seconds...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed, retrying in 2,0 seconds...
:success
```

---

relevant doc:

> :catch — should be a list of Exception classes that are going to be caught by retriable. The **default** value is [**java.io.IOException**]. Perseverance **doesn’t catch all exceptions intentionally** to avoid retrying the errors that aren’t IO-related, which would circumvent the proper error handling in your program. **Yet you can always provide :catch [Exception]** if you are sure that any potential exception inside is retriable

Comment: I understand why your example work, but not really why mine fails. I tried catching `RuntimeException` and even `Exception` and commented it.

Comment: it does not catch it, exactly *because* it's commented out

Comment: Right - I must have had some stale REPL state hanging around